# install shibboleth sp: Requires: libmemcached.so.2

Tags: shibboleth, libmemcached

I'm trying install shibboleth sp. I added the repository:

```
sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/security:shibboleth.repo  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/shibboleth/CentOS_7/security:shibboleth.repo
```

But when I run:

```
sudo yum install shibboleth.x86_64
```

I get:

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package shibboleth.x86_64 0:2.6.1-3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: opensaml-schemas(x86-64) >= 2.6.0 for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxmltooling.so.7()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxmltooling-lite.so.7()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxml-security-c.so.17()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxerces-c-3.1.so()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libsaml.so.9()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libodbc.so.2()(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libsaml9.x86_64 0:2.6.1-3.1 will be installed
---> Package libxml-security-c17.x86_64 0:1.7.3-3.3 will be installed
---> Package libxmltooling7.x86_64 0:1.6.3-3.1 will be installed
---> Package opensaml-schemas.x86_64 0:2.6.1-3.1 will be installed
---> Package shibboleth.x86_64 0:2.6.1-3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit) for package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.3.1-11.el7 will be installed
---> Package xerces-c.x86_64 0:3.1.1-8.el7_2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: shibboleth-2.6.1-3.1.x86_64 (security_shibboleth)
       Requires: libmemcached.so.2(libmemcached_2)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried many ways to install this lib, but didn't work.
My SO is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Dear i face the same problem while installing Catania Science Gateway and resolve this using the following steps

```
1) cd /etc/yum.repos.d
2) rm -f *Shibboleth* 
3) sudo curl -o /etc/yum.repos.d/shibboleth.repo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security://shibboleth/CentOS_7/security:shibboleth.repo
4) yum clean all
5) rm -rf /var/cache/yum 
6) yum update
7) yum install shibboleth
8) systemctl start shibd.service
```